# Java 8 Testing Concurrency

Tags: junit, java-8, executorservice, easymock, countdownlatch

SO...

I have this utility class that performs retries (to anything, theoretically) after the initial call has not returned after a given amount of time, and continually does so until any source returns data or until all are exhausted. This uses `ExecutorCompletionService`'s `.poll` method to trigger when to retry. See the following code for the utility class...

```
final RetrySources[] retrySources = getRetrySources(originalSource);

Future<T> resultFuture = null;
final List<Future<T>> futures = new ArrayList<>(retrySources.length);
for (int tryIndex = 0; tryIndex < retrySources.length && resultFuture == null; tryIndex++) {
    final int tryIndexCopy = tryIndex;
    futures.add(ecs.submit(() -> client.call(retrySources[tryIndexCopy], tryIndexCopy)));
    resultFuture = ecs.poll(millisBeforeRetry, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}

if (resultFuture == null) {
    resultFuture = ecs.take();
}

return resultFuture.get();
```

...my problem is that I am re-writing the tests to not use sleep, but instead to use `CountDownLatch`. See one of my tests below...

```
    @Test
    public void call_firstRetryFinishesAfterLimitButBeforeSecondRetryDoes_triggersSecondRetryButUsesFirstResult() throws Exception {
        final String readResult1 = "a";
        final String readResult2 = "b";

        final CountDownLatch signal1 = new CountDownLatch(1);
        final CountDownLatch signal2 = new CountDownLatch(1);

        expect(mockReadOperation.call(readOptions[0], 0)).andStubAnswer(() -> {
            signal1.await(); // This causes the test to spin forever
            // Thread.sleep(1000); // Swapping the line above for this, makes it work
            return readResult1;
        });

        expect(mockReadOperation.call(readOptions[1], 1)).andStubAnswer(() -> {
            signal1.countDown();
            signal2.await(); // For this test case, make the second retry never return
            return readResult2;
        });

        replay(mockReadOperation);

        final ReadOption readOption = ReadOption.primary();
        final String result = subject.call(readOption);

        assertThat(result).isEqualTo("a");
    }
```

...and note that my `ExecutorCompletionService` is defined...

```
private final ExecutorCompletionService executorCompletionService = new ExecutorCompletionService(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2));
```

...since my test is running in the main thread, and each call is running it it's own thread as part of the `ExecutorCompletionService` pool, I don't understand why having the `signal1.await();` causes the test to spin forever and note the comment, that switching that single line for a sleep, causes the test to pass.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a fully working test case? I would like to reproduce it. I suspect a deadlocking inside EasyMock synchronization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably due to `replay(mockReadOperation);` where you are activating(executing) the mocks. ??

Note: I have never used easy-mock, but a quick google reveals that `replay` activates the mocks and this seems to fit the answer, I may be wrong.

If I am right, and you always have to `replay` mocks in easymock, then maybe solution is,  switch to Mockito :p!

Comment: I think you are right; switching from EasyMock to stubbing the operation myself in each test seems to have fixed the issue! Not sure exactly why this is the case though...

Comment: It's probably because of the `replay` which is executing the mocks before they are needed.

Comment: The `replay` method does not execute the mocks. `replay` set the mock to some kind of "ready to be used" state.